# Python 3.5: Sort dictionary by key (dates)

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to sort a dictionary by key. The keys are datetime objects. It works for 1 April, 2 April, 3 April, but it puts 4 april between 1 and 2. I've tried Ordereddict like described [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

I'm just don't getting it. Any help appreciated...

My code:

```
for part in msg.walk():
        if partNum == 0:
            rawDate = part['Date']
            date = parse_date(rawDate)

        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            content = part.get_payload()
            splitted_content = content.split('\r\n')
            pending_tb = str(splitted_content[8])[70:].strip()

        if partNum == 2:
            values[date] = pending_tb
            #TODO sort by date


        partNum += 1


write_file(OrderedDict(sorted(values.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])))
```

The parse_date function:

```
def parse_date(rawdate):
    date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(rawdate)
    if date_tuple:
        date =  datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
        formatted_date = date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
        return formatted_date
else:
    print("ERROR: kon datum niet parsen.")
    exit(-1)
```

And the write_file function:

```
def write_file(values):
    filepath = "temp.csv"
    file = open(filepath, "a+")

    for k,v in sorted(values.items()):
        if len(k) > 0:
            file.write(k + "\t\t" + v + "\n")
```

Printscreen of output: http://prntscr.com/ao6qst

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your output, it looks like to me that the output isn't sorted by date (as in the number) but it is sorted in lexicographical order. Namely, `F` comes before `M` which comes before `S`

Comment: very simple, keep the `datetime` objects as keys instead of formatting them.  so comment out the line `formatted_date = date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")` and just `return date`.

Comment: That makes sense... I didn't notice that until now.. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should accept your answer so that this question doesn't remain in the unanswered list.  To do that, click the greyed-out check mark below the vote count on your answer.

Comment: Keep the dates as `datetime` and `sorted(dict)` sorts by key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like said in the comments, the dictionary sorted strings instead of datetime objects. So the solution is to return date, and format the date in the write file function.

Thanks for the fast answers!